# Disable scroll only by JS

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollbar, overflow

I have two divs but when I hide scrollbar on one it will be bugged on both, so I need to have overflow visible in CSS. But just disable scrolling with js. Specifically for div with id *chatcontent*.

Comment: Please include your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the overflow styling for an element by id 'chatcontent', via the following javascript:

```
// Disables the overflow behaviour for chatcontent
function disableOverflowForChatcontent() {
    document.getElementById('chatcontent').style.overflow = 'hidden';
}

// Resets the overflow behaviour for chatcontent
function resetOverflowForChatcontent() {
    document.getElementById('chatcontent').style.overflow = '';
}
```

Ideally, you would have CSS classes defined through which you would control `overflow` behaviour. Supposing you had the following CSS, then your javascript would be better written as:

**CSS:**

```
.overflow-none {
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

**JS:**

```
// Disables the overflow behaviour for chatcontent
function disableOverflowForChatcontent() {
    document.getElementById('chatcontent').classList.add('overflow-none');
}

// Resets the overflow behaviour for chatcontent
function resetOverflowForChatcontent() {
    document.getElementById('chatcontent').classList.remove('overflow-none');
}
```

Comment: Rather than setting/creating inline styles, it's best to dynamically add/remove a pre-existing CSS class with `.classList.add()` or `.classList.remove()`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes I agree, use of pre-existing classes is preferred. Hoping the answer works within possible constraints that the OP is working in. I've just updated the answer though to capture your suggestion - thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: But I want to have overflow: scroll; Only disabled by js

Comment: @WebCoder just updated answer to use `hidden` - does this work for you?

Comment: @DacreDenny when i hide overflow it get bugged.

Comment: @WebCoder can you give a little more detail - not sure what you mean by "it get bugged"

Comment: @DacreDenny This is chat without messages ctrlv.sk/0xAm. Max-height is not needed there. And this is chat with more messages ctrlv.sk/QXgc. And there max-height is needed but not works.

Comment: @WebCoder still not sure what you mean sorry. It might be more effective for you to outline your problem in more detail in a new question :-)

Comment: @DacreDenny https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53030557/max-height-doesnt-work-with-percentual-values