# Max-height doesn't work with percentual values

Tags: html, css

I have div in which is input which a don't want to be hidden when user scroll upper. And in that div is second div in wich are chat messages. But on first div is `max-height`  in percentual value and it's bugged. When I put there value in pixels it works but percentual values not. Can it get fixed?

Comment: maybe show us your code?

Comment: This is chat without messages https://ctrlv.sk/0xAm. Max-height is not needed there.  And this is chat with more messages https://ctrlv.sk/QXgc. And there max-height is needed but not works. Sorry that I don't put the code but it is so long code.

Comment: @Innervisions read message upper.

Comment: I assume you are talking about the chat in the middle where people exchange messages and you want to be able to scroll up and down?

Comment: @Innervisions sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing us your code would be easier but I guess the chat container doesn't have its height set. Percentual `max-height` defines the maximum height in percent of the containing block so if there's no explicit height set on your container `max-height` won't work. To resolve this either set a `height` on the chat container or use viewports units instead of % (e.g.: `max-height: 50vh` means 50% of the viewport height)